# MainWindow PreviewKeyDown slows TextBox input

Tags: wpf, textbox, keydown, event-bubbling

I'm using the `KeyDown` Event in my `MainWindow` to get key strokes of the up/down key.
When typing in a `TextBox` I get huge delays between key stroke and the character showing up on the screen, because of handling the `MainWindow.KeyDown` event after each stroke.

Is there a possibility to catch the up/down keys no matter what control is focused (also TextBoxes) without having this delay?
I could disable the event while the TextBox has focus but then I would miss the up/down keys.
I also tried to handle up/down keys in the `TextBox.KeyDown` event and prevent bubbling to the `MainWindow` by setting `e.Handled = true` but this also prevents the TextBox from showing anything at all.

Thanks for any help in advance!